# Жители Вологды

Tags: словообразование

Вчера неожиданно зависла на названии жителей Вологды - не могла сообразить, как их назвать. Потом пришло в голову - "вологодцы". Правильно или нет?
Спасибо

Comment: Я называю коренных жителей Вологды вологжанами, а пришлых жителей Вологды  вологодцами.

P.S. Ещё мне нравится слушать окающую речь вологжан.

Comment: Об этом не надо соображать. Надо знать. Для того и справочная литература. В доинтернетовские времена для определения разных заковыристых вопросиков надо было рыться в читалках, энциклопедиях, словарях и т.д. У меня была еще нахальная манера звонить в авторитетные газеты и журналы соответствующим редакторам - техническим, литературным и проч. Здорово выручало. Про "вологжан" и прочих "пермяков" и "тверичан" почему-то знаю с детства. Наверное потому, что дома радио не выключалось, и в виде фона усваивались многие и разнообразные знания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вологодцы - это не правильно. Верным вариантом будет **вологжане: вологжанин и вологжанка**.

Вообще с топонимами Вологодской области трудно разобраться даже местным жителям, ни говоря уже об иногородних. Самые частые ошибки:

- *Великий **У**стюг* - ударение на первый слог,
- река *С**у**хона*, и соответственно прочие названия от реки ударение на "у" сохраняют.

Из орфографических тонкостей есть Усть-КУб**и**нский район (ударение на "у"), с административным центром в Городе Устье, расположенным на месте впадения реки КУб**е**на в КУб**е**нское озеро.

Наименование жителей других населённых пунктов и местностей Вологодской области (ударение выделяю жирным шрифтом)

- Черепов**е**ц - череповч**а**не,
- Великий **У**стюг и **У**стюжна - устюж**а**не,
- Белоз**е**рск - белоз**е**рцы,
- Гр**я**зовец и его район - грязовч**а**не,
- Т**а**рнога и её район - тарнож**а**не,
- Ник**о**льск и его район - *никольч**а**не,
- Ш**у**я - шуяк**и**, а в её районе - междур**е**ченцы.
- **У**стье - усть**я**не, а его район - устьк**у**бинцы,
- Л**и**пин Бор - липинб**о**рцы, а в его районе - в**а**шкинцы.

Answer (score 2):

Чётких правил по поводу названия жителей того или иного населённого пункта сейчас нет, для этого используются различные суффиксы, ведь названия самих этих пунктов  бывают и существительными мужских – женских родов, и прилагательными, и состоящими из нескольких слов. К тому же, ранее и некоторые города назывались несколько иначе, чем сейчас, и люди говорили по-другому,   По старинным правилам  жители Вологды называются вологжане, как и жители Мурома, Смоленска, Курска («муромляне», «смоляне» и «куряне»). Попробую проанализировать, почему не «вологодцы». Во-первых, мужчину вы легко назовёте «вологодец»,  женщине пришлось бы придумывать что-то другое, подобно: пскович – псковитянка. Вологжанин же спокойно трансформируется в вологжанку. Во-вторых,  суффикс «ец» более подходит для определения принадлежности к какой-либо группировке. Например: «котовец», «чапаевец», «гитлировец». Я не уверен, но, как мне кажется, появился этот суффикс в нашем языке не так давно, как жители Вологды стали называть себя «вологжанами».

Comment: Муромляне похоже на муравьяне. Не лучше ли муромчане? Мурманчане и проч.?

Comment: >уффикс «ец» более подходит для определения принадлежности к какой-либо группировке. Например: «котовец», «чапаевец», «гитлировец». Я не уверен, но, как мне кажется, появился этот суффикс в нашем языке не так давно, как жители Вологды стали называть себя «вологжанами»

Вологда основана в XIII веке (официально в 1147 году, но на самом деле намного позднее), новгородцы, ярославцы, черниговцы, белозерцы появились существенно раньше.

Comment: Я и говорю, что не уверен, с удовольствием прочёл бы кокой-нибудь старинный текст, где встречается определение жителей, означенных вами городов, если не в тягость, порекомендуйте, пожалуйста!